# Ubuntu 16.04 Amazon app commission?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, amazon

I wanted to know if I buy something off the pre-installed Ubuntu Amazon App does canonical or the Ubuntu project get commission from it? 16.04 version of the app has significantly improved since the 14.04 version but it's still has a few odds and ends that make me use the web browser instead, when I am ready to make a purchase I go to the Ubuntu Amazon app to finalize it because I am hoping they get some commission from the sale. Do they or am I just wasting my time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is amazon have a very successful affiliation system and canonical use it. www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/ubuntu-online-search-feature-disabled-16-04